# Hibernate Enum mapping not creating mysql enum

Tags: hibernate

I'm currently using Hibernate with MySql. 
I'm trying to map an enum type, which according to several examples seems really straight forward.

However, the column that is generated contains a VARCHAR(255) rather than an enum type like it expected.

Here's the simple enum class.

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

Here's the annotation

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "gender")
public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}
```

And here's the field that's generated from this

```
| gender  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I can't see why the type is a String rather than an enum. 
I've tried changing the Enum type to Ordinal, but then I just get an Integer rather than a string, still no enum.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because ENUM is not a standard SQL datatype. By default @Enumerated is mapped to integer, if EnumType.STRING is used then column is mapped to a string.

Comment: Enum is a supported MySQL datatype - used here in a sample database. This article was recently updated - also links to MySQL documentation. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html Also - this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076604/mysql-enum-with-hibernate?rq=1